# ElasticSearch - aggregations on nested fields to return additional field in buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, nested, aggregation, bucket

I don't know if it is possible to return additional fields in the response for each bucket.
The current request returns correct results, but I'm missing additional field information required for later processing.

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": {
            "match_all": {}
        }
    }
},
"track_total_hits": true,
"from": 0,
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
    "strings": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "filter_data.string_facet"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "names": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "filter_data.string_facet.facet-name"
                },
                "aggs": {
                    "values": {
                        "terms": {
                            "field": "filter_data.string_facet.facet-value"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the result. Note the data in field **filter_data** how nested fields are structured.

```
{
"took": 1,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": {
        "value": 2,
        "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [{
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "7000043",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
            "item_data": {
                "doc_id": 7000043,
                "id": 7000043,
                "live_state": 1,
                "item_sku": "7000043",
                "manufacturer_id": 1394
            },
            "filter_data": {
                "string_facet": [{
                    "facet-name": "Thread size",
                    "facet-value": "G1/2",
                    "facet-name-id": 12,
                    "facet-value-id": 34
                }]
            }
        }
    }]
},
"aggregations": {
    "strings": {
        "doc_count": 5,
        "names": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [{
                "key": "Thread size",
                "doc_count": 2,
                "values": {
                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                    "buckets": [{
                        "key": "G1 1/4",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    }, {
                        "key": "G1/2",
                        "doc_count": 1
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add additional fields to each bucket? It would be ideal to have such a format in the response. Basically add field **facet-name-id** anf **facet-value-id** to each bucket.

```
....
    "buckets": [{
        "key": "Thread size",
        "doc_count": 2,
        "values": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [{
                "key": "G1 1/4",
                "facet-name-id": 12,
                "facet-value-id": 34
                "doc_count": 1
            }, {
                "key": "G1/2",
                "facet-name-id": 12,
                "facet-value-id": 35
                "doc_count": 1
            }]
        }
    }]
...
```

If this is not possible, what would you recommend?

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) as a sub-aggrgation of your deepest `facet-value` aggregation:

```json
POST my_index/_search?filter_path=aggregations.*.*.buckets.key,aggregations.*.*.buckets.values.buckets.key,aggregations.*.*.buckets.values.buckets.*.hits.hits._source
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "strings": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "filter_data.string_facet"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "names": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "filter_data.string_facet.facet-name"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "values": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "filter_data.string_facet.facet-value"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "my_top_hits": {
                  "top_hits": {
                    "size": 10,
                    "_source": ["filter_data.string_facet"]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which'd yield:

```json
{
  "aggregations" : {
    "strings" : {
      "names" : {
        "buckets" : [
          {
            "key" : "Thread size",
            "values" : {
              "buckets" : [
                {
                  "key" : "G1/2",
                  "my_top_hits" : {
                    "hits" : {
                      "hits" : [
                        {
                          "_source" : {
                            "facet-value" : "G1/2",
                            "facet-name" : "Thread size",
                            "facet-value-id" : 34,
                            "facet-name-id" : 12
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice that `my_top_hits` is an **array** of `string_facet` objects instead of an **object** as you requested. That's because although you're already 2 facets deep (`facet-name` and then `facet-value`), there *may* still be multiple different `facet-value-id` and `facet-name-id` combinations covered by a given `facet-value` bucket.

Having said that, you can of course limit the `top_hits` count with the `size` parameter but then you wouldn't be able to say with certainty whether or not the first top hit's facets are representative of the whole bucket .

Comment: Thank you i will test it. I've read somewhere about top_hits solutions. How about top_hits performance, is it negligible? I don't have test data yet, but I'm counting on more than a million records.

Comment: Top hits of size 10 should be negligible. But they are accessing the `_source` attributes which are I/O-heavy so ... if you greatly increase the higher level agg sizes, the top hits may begin to downgrade the retrieval speeds.